# Set Foundation modal top property to Y coordinate of mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to set the CSS top property to the Y coordinate of a mouse click using jQuery, but nothing I've tried so far has overwritten the Foundation Zurb top property for the modal.  Oddly though, my code does correctly assign the X coordinate of the mouse click to the left property for the modal.  This is my jQuery attempt:

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('a.open-mobile').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#mobile-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    });
    $('#house-mobile').click(function (e) { //Default mouse Position 
        console.log(e.pageX + ' , ' + e.pageY);
        mouseX = e.pageX; 
        mouseY = e.pageY;
        $('#mobile-modal').css({'top':mouseY, 'left':mouseX});
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a xlink:href="#" class="open-mobile" data-reveal-id="mobile-modal" title="Mobile devices" id="house-mobile">
    <img... />
</a>

<div id="mobile-modal" class="reveal-modal image-modals mobile-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <p>Text here.</p>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Custom CSS:

```
.image-modals {
    width: 380px !important;
    height: auto;
    padding: 34px !important;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
}
#mobile-modal {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

I've read that since e.pageY is a number, I don't need to append "px" onto it, though I tried appending `"px !important"` anyway, just in case, but it still didn't work.  I also tried appending `" !important"` to mouseY, but still no dice.  I've tried setting .mobile-img CSS top to 0 in the CSS file and then running the code, but no change.  If I set the CSS to 100px, Foundation will add 100px to it's own top property value.  But I want to replace the Foundation top value with the Y coordinate of my mouse click.  Why does the X work, but the Y doesn't?  I think that Foundation Zurb javascript is determining the top value for the modal, but why can't I override that?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You actually do need to append "px" to the value, since the value you're passing is no longer a number after you append " !important" to it.

Comment: Thank you.  I did try that as well appending it like this `"px !important"` but it still didn't work. :(

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think you should either use `screenY` or `clientY` instead of `pageY`. I'm not familiar with foundation, but I think their modal uses fixed position relative to the window, not the document. I.e. a `top: 700px` is 700px from the top of the window, not 700px from the top of your document. So your modal may show but it's hidden out of the browser's view.

Comment: I can see the modal every time it pops up, except when I added `top: 2600` to the .mobile-modal class in the CSS file, because that time it just added 2600 to the Foundation top value of 2535, so the modal showed 5000+ pixels down the screen.  That's the only thing that has actually affected the top value of the modal.  Everything I've tried with jQuery hasn't worked.  I can tell you that Foundation is definitely positioning the modal from the top of the document.  I did try your `screenY` and `clientY` suggestions though, and unfortunately they didn't do anything different.